# Nginx always falls back to default config

Tags: django, nginx

My stack is django, gunicorn, nginx and supervisor running on a VPS from DigitalOcean.

Supervisor is running the program correctly but I always get the NGINX welcome page. If I delete the default nginx config file everything works and I get the website.

Here are my custom settings:

```
upstream maet_app_server {
  # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
  # to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
  # single worker for timing out).

  server unix:/webapps/maet/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    listen   80;
    server_name maet.bg www.maet.com;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /webapps/maet/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /webapps/maet/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias   /webapps/maet/website/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias   /webapps/maet/website/static/;
    }

    location / {
        # an HTTP header important enough to have its own Wikipedia entry:
        #   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # enable this if and only if you use HTTPS, this helps Rack
        # set the proper protocol for doing redirects:
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

        # pass the Host: header from the client right along so redirects
        # can be set properly within the Rack application
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
        # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
        proxy_redirect off;

        # set "proxy_buffering off" *only* for Rainbows! when doing
        # Comet/long-poll stuff.  It's also safe to set if you're
        # using only serving fast clients with Unicorn + nginx.
        # Otherwise you _want_ nginx to buffer responses to slow
        # clients, really.
        # proxy_buffering off;

        # Try to serve static files from nginx, no point in making an
        # *application* server like Unicorn/Rainbows! serve static files.
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://maet_app_server;
            break;
        }
    }

    # Error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /webapps/maet/website/static/;
    }
}
```

How do I change it to use this config instead of the default one?

I don't want to delete the default file because I need it for let's encrypt ssl.

Comment: Check the `server_name` values. `nginx` will use the `default_server` if it cannot find a port and server name match in any other `server` block.

Comment: @RichardSmith That was it I changed it to listen 8080 default_server;
 listen [::]:8080 default_server; for anyone who faces the same problem